# The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (1, 0) error

Tags: python, scipy, hypothesis-test

I study to do a chi-square independence test and I'm using python, scipy.stats for it. For the first 8 columns, it's testing as expected but when it's in 9th column there is occuring an error like:

```
The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (1, 0) error
```

I wrote a function to automatize test for all columns. These are my codes:

```
def independence_test(col_1, col_2 = "covid19"):
  ct = pd.crosstab(df[col_2], df[col_1], margins=True)
  obs = np.array([ct.iloc[0][0:5].values,
                  ct.iloc[1][0:5].values])
  test_result = chi2_contingency(obs)[0:3]
  return test_result
```

In an another stackoverflow question it says that put the cross table to chi2_contingency function directly but when I do it, p values being greater than 1.0 and as I know, this can not be true. How can I handle this error?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The first argument to [`chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) must be a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table), not your arrays of raw data.